# Looking for $\tan\frac{1}{2}\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $$\frac{\cos \theta}{1-\sin\theta}=a,$$ 
how can I find the value of $\tan\frac{1}{2}\theta$?

I went in this way,
[image]

but the matter is in the box as shown (the fallacies).

Comment: Do you know the formula to express $\sin \theta$ only in terms of $\tan \frac 12 \theta$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta}=a$$
$$\frac{\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}}{1-\frac{2\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}}=a$$
$$\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}-2\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}=a$$
$$(a+1)\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}-2a\tan\frac{\theta}{2}+(a-1)=0$$

now solve quadratic for $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$,
$$\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{2a\pm\sqrt{4a^2-4(a+1)(a-1)}}{2(a+1)}=\frac{a\pm1}{a+1}$$ 
hope it answers

Comment: But, for $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{a+1}{a+1}=1$ implies $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is undefined for the initial equation.